# Are opencv samples in diamondback debs?

Tags: ros, vision-opencv, opencv2.2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently upgraded to diamondback release (installed on Ubuntu 10.04 from apt-get). As I recall, the samples for opencv used to be in the opencv2 package directory -- however, it appears they no longer are? Am I looking in the wrong place or is this due to the cleanup that was done to reduce the size of the .debs?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9287/are-opencv-samples-in-diamondback-debs?/) by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13902 on 2011-03-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like this was due to the cleanup of the debs.

If you checkout and build the `opencv2` package from source (with e.g. `svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/vision_opencv/trunk/opencv2` and then CD into that package and type `make`), you'll find that it does download and build the samples, but they are never moved out of the `build` directory. Part of the deb cleanup was to remove all `build` directories from packages so that the debs did not include a bunch of intermediate object files, only finished executables and libraries.

If you think that the samples should be available to deb users, filing a [ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/newticket?component=vision_opencv&type=defect&&vision_opencv) would be the best way to get them re-included. If the samples are large, it might be best for the build system to provide a second .deb that includes just the samples that could be installed in addition to the standard `vision_opencv` deb file. I can't really say whether or not the samples were intentionally kept out to keep the debs small or if it was just an oversight.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) on 2011-03-07**:
I'm also in favour of having an extra package with both OpenCV and OpenCV2 samples.

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-03-07**:
This is basically what I thought, I wanted to confirm that I wasn't looking in the wrong place. Thanks Erik

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-03-07**:
Generally, building/editing files inside the deb-packaged version install is a poor idea. A much better solution is to overlay the package/stack you want to develop with using something like rosinstall (or by checking it out onto your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH).

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-03-06**:
"roscd opencv2" and "make" should also work for the deb-packaged version. You need root access though.